# How does Edmonds-karp algorithm actually computes the shortest path?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, edmonds-karp

I am trying to understand Edmonds-Karp algorithm in more details and was curious to know what algorithm it uses to compute the shortest path (least number of edges) from s to t for each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breadth-first search. You might want to read the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) for details.